# Lettrine slightly misaligned with text different fontsize

Tags: vertical-alignment, lettrine

I have this code:

```
\usepackage[a5paper, total=5in, 7.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=4]{\color{albastru} \textquotedbl S}{} {\fontsize{20}{10}\selectfont top being so full of life...}

\setlength{\parindent}{7em}

{{\fontsize{20}{60}\selectfont Open your wallet instead!\textquotedbl} \hfill}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\hfill {\color{albastru} \emph{{\fontsize{15}{40} \selectfont Someone smart}}}
```

It produces this:

[image: The result of the code]

I want the text to be a bit more down (aligned with the S). At the moment, the text is a few pixels off. What can I change?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `\lettrine[lines=4, lraise=0.1]{\color{blue} \textquotedbl S}{}`

Comment: please post example code in a form that shows the problem, I tried to add `\documentclass{article}` and got `! Package keyval Error: 7.5in undefined.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a simplified code.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    

\lettrine[lines=5, lraise=0.1]{\color{blue} \textquotedbl S}{} \fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont top being so full of life...

\hspace{2.5em} Open your wallet instead!\textquotedbl 

\smallskip
\hfill \emph{\color{blue}\fontsize{15}{20} \selectfont Someone smart}
    
\end{document}
```